# How do I typedef a function pointer with the using syntax into class?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have class

**file.h**

```
class SpiDriver {
    using ptrSpiFunc = bool (SpiDriver::*)(SpiConfig_t&);
    static ptrSpiFunc checkFlagFunc[9];
public:
    SpiDriver() {};
    static bool flagFre(SpiConfig_t&);
};
```

**file.cpp**

```
SpiDriver::ptrSpiFunc SpiDriver::checkFlagFunc[9] = { &SpiDriver::flagFre };

bool SpiDriver::flagFre(SpiConfig_t& cfg) {
    return false;
}
```

I get an error when compiling

```
Error[Pe144]: a value of type "bool (*)(SpiConfig_t &)" cannot be
used to initialize an entity of type "SpiDriver::ptrSpiFunc"
```

Comment: You define `ptrSpiFunc` to be a pointer to a ***non-static*** member function. Static member functions are similar to non-member functions, in that they have no specific object to be called on. Perhaps `std::function<bool(SpiConfig_t&)>` might be a better choice here?

Answer (score 2):

The `flagFre` is a static member function, and their function pointer type is like non-member (free functions).

Therefore, you need either

```
using ptrSpiFunc = bool (*)(SpiConfig_t&);
//                      ^^^^ --> Since it doesn't required "SpiDriver" object!
```

or as *@Someprogrammerdude* mentioned

```
#include <functional> // std::function

using ptrSpiFunc = std::function<bool(SpiConfig_t&)>;
```

to work with them.